# Trouble analysing spreadsheet using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, spreadsheet

Im trying to find a way to compare what students performed consistantly in their InternalAssessment_Performance to their FinalExam_Performance. Essentially i need to find what students have the same answer in both those columns. 
How is it possible to compare the values in both commons and have them returned if they are the same?
Any help no matter how small would be great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values

Comment: Please provide sample data, what you've tried so far, and your expected output.

Comment: You need to share far more information than this. Please see: [mcve], [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns are aligned you can do something like this:

```
df[df['InternalAssessment_Performance'] == df['FinalExam_Performance']]
```

Comment: Yes this works perfect thankyou, lets say i needed to compare it to more columns too. Would i simple just add more '=='?

Comment: yes, add them with parens: like this: df[(df['InternalAssessment_Performance'] == df['FinalExam_Performance']) & ( df['another'] == df['anotherone'])]